# jQuery: How to match heights of multiple sets of divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so I don't entirely know what I'm doing... But at least I'm trying. Sorry if this has been asked before. I've been searching for hours on some insight and can't find what I need. Or maybe I'm just not using the right keywords... Anyway.

I want to set the height of `.float-fix` to the same height as `.float-height`. The reason for this is to get the `#wrapper` to completely cover the content inside it. But, I need to do this for more than one `.float-fix` and `.float-height`. I've set them apart with name attributes so I can separate/match them, as I don't want both of my `.float-fix` to take the height of the first `.float-height`, only the `.float-height` they are bundled with.

In other words, I want `.float-fix[name=1]` to take the height of `.float-height[name=1]`, and `.float-fix[name=2]` to take the height of `.float-height[name=2]`. I also need it to be flexible for more float bundles, not just these two, and the heights will change with the window size so setting it with a solid number won't do.

The code I came up with and am having troubles getting to work is:

```
var myNum =  $('.float-fix').attr('name');

$('.float-fix[name=' + myNum + ']').height(
    $('.float-height[name=' + this.name + ']').height()
);
```

I would appreciate any help you guys can offer. Hopefully what I said wasn't too confusing...

Here's all the coding I have for the project I'm talking about so you can better understand what's going on:

```js
function fixFloat() {
 var fix2nd = float2nd($('#wrapper').width(), 2, 15);
 function float2nd(a, b, c) {
  return a / b - c
 }
  
 $('.float-2nd').width(fix2nd);
 
 var fix3rd = float3rd($('#wrapper').width(), 3, 13.33);
 function float3rd(a, b, c) {
  return a / b - c
 }
  
 $('.float-3rd').width(fix3rd);
 
 var fix4th = float4th($('#wrapper').width(), 4, 12.5);
 function float4th(a, b, c) {
  return a / b - c
 }
 
 $('.float-4th').width(fix4th);
}

$('.float-bun').each(function(i) {
 $(this).find('.float-height').attr('name', ++i);
 $(this).find('.float-fix').attr('name', ++i);
});

function bunHeight() {
 var myNum =  $('.float-fix').attr('name');
  
 $('.float-fix[name=' + myNum + ']').height(
  $('.float-height[name=' + this.name + ']').height()
 );
}

$(document).ready(fixFloat).ready(bunHeight);
$(window).resize(fixFloat).resize(bunHeight);
```

```css
#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
 width: 58%;
 min-width: 600px;
 max-width: 2500px;
 background-color: rgba(60,60,60,0.5);
}

.float-bun, .float-fix {margin: 0;}

.float-cont, .float-height {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
}

.float {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur blandit ullamcorper. Vivamus ultrices leo eget erat eleifend, a consequat urna luctus. Aenean cursus auctor augue, maximus eleifend risus placerat eget.</div>
  
 <div class="float-bun">
  <div class="float-height" name="0">
   <div class="float-cont">
    <div class="float float-2nd" style="background: red;">float 1</div>
    <div class="float float-2nd" style="background: blue;">float 2</div>
   </div>
     
   <div class="float-cont">
    <div class="float float-3rd" style="background: red;">float 1</div>
    <div class="float float-3rd" style="background: green;">float 2</div>
    <div class="float float-3rd" style="background: blue;">float 3</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-fix" name="0"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="float-bun">
  <div class="float-height" name="0">
   <div class="float-cont">
    <div class="float float-4th" style="background: red;">float 1</div>
    <div class="float float-4th" style="background: green;">float 2</div>
    <div class="float float-4th" style="background: blue;">float 3</div>
    <div class="float float-4th" style="background: yellow;">float 4</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-fix" name="0"></div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: do you want the `wrapper` to cover up all the contents? its that all u want?

Comment: if all you need to do is get the contents inside of the `.wrapper` you just need to do is put `.wrapper{overflow:hidden;}` no need for javascript. this will cope all the floated elements inside of it

Comment: Oh, wow... That was super simple... Thanks @Ron.Basco that's exactly what I needed. Haha...

Comment: Also, thanks for the link @Selvam. I'll most likely use that for another project.